# Extracting leading spaces from the rest of the string

Tags: php, string

What is the quickest approach to splitting a string into its leading spaces and the rest of it?

`····sth` should become `array("····", "sth")` and `·sth·` - `array("·", "sth·")`

* `·` = space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = preg_split('/^(\s*)/', '  test ', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

outputs

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "  "
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler approach:

```
$result = preg_split('/\b/', '   sth', 2);
```

It would output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '   ' (length=3)
  1 => string 'sth' (length=3)
```